# Why does my loop only return one answer instead of answers for the entire list?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to do a precourse assignment for lambda School and Loops are giving me the worst headache. I have a 2d list of names with heights and weights. heights were givin in cm so i used a loop to convert it to m. Then to calculate the BMI, I tried running a l;oop but it keeps giving me only the last one. Let me type the code so it makes more sense.

```
person_data2

[['John', 84.5, 184],
 ['Ryan', 81.8, 177],
 ['Bobby', 86.1, 190],
 ['Pete', 92.2, 188],
 ['Esther', 69.6, 159],
 ['Jane', 72.0, 166],
 ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]
```

Changed heights from cm to m using the loop below and it worked

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data2):
  person_data2[i][2] = person_data2[i][2] / 100

print(person_data2)

[['John', 84.5, 1.84], 
['Ryan', 81.8, 1.77], 
['Bobby', 86.1, 1.9], 
['Pete', 92.2, 1.88], 
['Esther', 69.6, 1.59], 
['Jane', 72.0, 1.66], 
['Samantha', 51.3, 1.62]]
```

BMI = weight/(height^2)
So I ran this

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data2):
  BMI2 = ((person_data2[i][1])/(person_data2[i][2]**2))

print (BMI2)

19.547325102880652
```

Why does it only run the last nested list BMI ie Samanthas BMI and not the rest? TBH I dont understand loops fully and changing from cm to m was a bit of copy and paste and trial and error. Could someone point me to what I am doing wrong? And if you know any resources I could use to help me get this right, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Print INSIDE the loop. The way you do it, you print only the LAST value

Comment: Do you want BMI2 to be a list?

Comment: Yes, I want BMI2 to return a list with everyones BMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the values only, using the print inside the loop will help:

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data2):
  BMI2 = ((person_data2[i][1])/(person_data2[i][2]**2))
  print (BMI2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
24.958648393194707
26.109993935331477
23.850415512465375
26.086464463558173
27.530556544440483
26.1286108288576
19.547325102880652
```

But if you want to return a list at the end of the loop, Try storing the values in a list like this :

```
BMI2=[]
for i, person in enumerate(person_data2):
  x = ((person_data2[i][1])/(person_data2[i][2]**2))
  BMI2.append(x)

print (BMI2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[24.958648393194707,
 26.109993935331477,
 23.850415512465375,
 26.086464463558173,
 27.530556544440483,
 26.1286108288576,
 19.547325102880652]
```

Comment: you rock! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
Your `print()` is out of your loop, just change your code to this and place your `print()` in your loop:

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data2):
  BMI2 = ((person_data2[i][1])/(person_data2[i][2]**2))
  print (BMI2)
```

Comment: To think this tiny thing had me about to pull my hair out. I just started learning Python but slowly getting the hang of it. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ChiamakaEzeamama Good luck with learning python and always try to improve your skills.

Answer (score 0):

`BMI2` is overwritten in each loop iteration. Since your `print` is outside the loop, the output will be the last calculated `BMI2` (the one from the last iteration).

Try the following in order to print the bmi for each person in your dataset:

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data2):
    BMI2 = ((person_data2[i][1])/(person_data2[i][2]**2))
    print (BMI2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was all i had to do!